# AWS Elastic Beanstalk failed to install psycopg2 using requirements.txt Git Pip

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy an app using elasticbeanstalk with Python 3.8. I am using the following requirements.txt

```
click==8.0.1
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
greenlet==1.1.0
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
marshmallow==3.12.1
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.25.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.15
Werkzeug==2.0.1
celery[redis]
psycopg2==2.9.3
Flask-JWT-Extended==4.3.1
Flask-RESTful==0.3.9
python-decouple==3.6
```

When I run the command eb create, I get the following error

```
2022-04-05 22:03:00    INFO    Created security group named: sg-00b14485064e5e8ca
2022-04-05 22:03:16    INFO    Created security group named: awseb-e-ekd3bw2bvf-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-1O3NAVBIRRK30
2022-04-05 22:03:31    INFO    Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-ekd3bw2bvf-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-HKjIVsa84E3U
2022-04-05 22:04:49    INFO    Created Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-ekd3bw2bvf-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-5FQOAWMGCR3W
2022-04-05 22:04:49    INFO    Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
2022-04-05 22:04:49    INFO    Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:208357543212:scalingPolicy:ecfbbff0-4151-492f-a474-ba01535ad348:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-ekd3bw2bvf-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-5FQOAWMGCR3W:policyName/awseb-e-ekd3bw2bvf-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy-CI2UIP6X023P
2022-04-05 22:04:49    INFO    Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:208357543212:scalingPolicy:d534189a-45e3-48f1-a206-720f202b4469:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-ekd3bw2bvf-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-5FQOAWMGCR3W:policyName/awseb-e-ekd3bw2bvf-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicy-1F0WVTUXXPFKF
2022-04-05 22:05:04    INFO    Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-ekd3bw2bvf-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-W8URMJEYBO3C
2022-04-05 22:05:04    INFO    Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-ekd3bw2bvf-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh-13J8QHI51MEBM
2022-04-05 22:06:09    INFO    Created load balancer named: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:208357543212:loadbalancer/app/awseb-AWSEB-IXOR2Z0K0OJV/1fba4c6ff6122c55
2022-04-05 22:06:24    INFO    Created Load Balancer listener named: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:208357543212:listener/app/awseb-AWSEB-IXOR2Z0K0OJV/1fba4c6ff6122c55/734b0cf960b6b8c4
2022-04-05 22:06:42    ERROR   Instance deployment failed to install application dependencies. The deployment failed.
2022-04-05 22:06:42    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2022-04-05 22:06:44    ERROR   [Instance: i-0368a7ba2157241f4] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
2022-04-05 22:06:45    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2022-04-05 22:07:48    ERROR   Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

I look at the corresponding logs and I get the following error:

```
Collecting Werkzeug==2.0.1
  Downloading Werkzeug-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (288 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 288.2/288.2 KB 35.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting celery[redis]
  Downloading celery-5.2.6-py3-none-any.whl (405 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 405.6/405.6 KB 54.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting psycopg2==2.9.3
  Downloading psycopg2-2.9.3.tar.gz (380 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 380.6/380.6 KB 52.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

2022/04/05 22:06:42.952376 [INFO]   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-v0aygozt/psycopg2.egg-info
      writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-v0aygozt/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-v0aygozt/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-v0aygozt/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-v0aygozt/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      
      Error: pg_config executable not found.
      
      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:
      
          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
      
      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
      
      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I am not quite familiar with the requirements of AWS, but I could run the app locally and without any problem. I just wonder what would be a right configuration for the requirements.txt file in order to avoid the bug.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Yes. I forget give the check to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the error. I have to change `psycopg2` by `psycopg2-binary` as it was suggested by the AWS logs:

```
If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
```

This issue has to be with the particular configuration of the libraries and the specific Linux machines used in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `postgresql-devel` first before you can use `psycopg2`. You can add the installation instructions to your [ebextentions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-packages=):

```
packages: 
  yum:
    postgresql-devel: []
```

or

```
commands:
  command1:
    command: yum install -y postgresql-devel
```